# Importing a DataRow to a new DataTable results in error. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datarow

I've been put on an older project vb.net project. I am trying to query a datatable and import the resulting DataRow into a newly created DataTable.

Code:

```
    Private Sub FilterSelectedByString(ByVal str As String, ByVal mID As Integer)
        Try
            dsTargetEmployees = MemberShipManager.GetMessageTargets(_page.Client, mID)
            dtTargets = dsTargets.Tables("MessageTargets")
            Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
            For Each dr As DataRow In dtTargets.Select(str)
                dt.ImportRow(dr)
            Next
            lstSelected.Items.Clear()
            lstSelected.DataSource = dt
            lstSelected.DataTextField = "EmployeeName"
            lstSelected.DataValueField = "EmployeeID"
            lstSelected.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
           //error code
        End Try
    End Sub
```

This results in an "object not set to an instance of an object" error in the for loop. I've tried creating the data columns in the table manually, but that also results in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem. Copying the original table into the created table then clearing it built the correct structure.

```
Private Sub FilterSelectedByString(ByVal str As String, ByVal mID As Integer)
    Try
        dsTargetEmployees = MemberShipManager.GetMessageTargets(_page.Client, mID)
        dtTargets = dsTargets.Tables("MessageTargets")
        Dim dt As DataTable = dtTargets.Copy()
        dt.Clear()
        For Each dr As DataRow In dtTargets.Select(str)
            dt.ImportRow(dr)
        Next
        lstSelected.Items.Clear()
        lstSelected.DataSource = dt
        lstSelected.DataTextField = "EmployeeName"
        lstSelected.DataValueField = "EmployeeID"
        lstSelected.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
       //error code
    End Try
End Sub
```